# RxJs pipes as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

how to pass pipes as parameter
, I mean something like this :

```
var mypipes = [
               pipeA(() => {
                alert("a"); 
               })
               ,
              pipeB(() => {
                alert("b"); 
               })
             ];

of(arg1, arg2, arg3).pipe(mypipes).subscribe();
```

I got this error :
provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'

Comment: What's `pipeA` and `pipeB`? If there're operators you can use `pipe(...mypipes)`

Comment: @martin pipeA and pipeB are my custom pipes (like tap,finalize from rxjs/operators)  ...

Comment: So they're operators

Comment: @martin yes but .pipe(mypipes) not works

Comment: `pipe(...mypipes)` does work

Comment: Try with three dots as martin originally stated

Comment: @martin  I got this : "error TS2557: Expected at least 0 arguments, but got 0 or more."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just `pipe(...operators)` but you'll have to define exact length of your array so `pipe()` knows what override to use:

```
const operators: [OperatorFunction<number, number>, OperatorFunction<number, number>] = [
  tap(v => console.log(v)),
  tap(v => console.log(v)),
];

of(1, 2).pipe(...operators).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

Or you could use just `[any, any]` as well.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-s9efsr?devtoolsheight=60